# How does a cascode current mirror maintain equal Vds of the bottom transistors?

Tags: mosfet, current-mirror, cascode

A basic current mirror is shown below:

[image]

The load and reference current relationship is affected by channel length modulation:
[image]

In order to cancel the effects of channel length modulation, vds1 and vds2 need to be  equal. A cascode current mirror is needed to make this happen, but how? The book I'm using is by Razavi..
[image]

Vn = Vgs3 + Vds2

Then, in order to make Vds1=Vds2, vn must satisfy:

Vn = Vgs3 + Vds1   or
Vn  = Vgs3 + Vgs1

But from the circuit:

Vn=Vgs0 + Vgs1 !!!

How are Vgs0 and Vgs3 equal?